# Does CAS support authorize difference user to different service (aka third party cas client)

Tags: authentication, authorization, cas

Say I have a lot of `CAS` clients, and the different user gets limited access permission to the different system, how can I control the access control of the users in `CAS` system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you fail to mention your CAS server version, in CAS 5.2.x the access strategy of a registered service provides fine-grained control over the service authorization rules. It describes whether the service is allowed to use the CAS server, allowed to participate in single sign-on authentication, etc. Additionally, it may be configured to require a certain set of principal attributes that must exist before access can be granted to the service. This behavior allows one to configure various attributes in terms of access roles for the application and define rules that would be enacted and validated when an authentication request from the application arrives.

See https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuring-Service-Access-Strategy.html